# How to login heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have disabled 2f authentication, after that, I can not log in to Heroku, always ask the authentication how, how can I get the authentication code?

[image]

Comment: A a shot in the dark: As of April 8, 2021 Two-factor authentication has been deprecated https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/two-factor-authentication and replaced by MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multi-factor-authentication. Try to find out if u have MFA enabled and disable it too.

Comment: @DVN-Anakin, now I can do nothing, without login how to change the configuration? Need help with login.

Comment: In that case have u tried clicking on "I forgot my password"? Maybe if u reset your password via emal, u won't have to verify your identity anymore. If that doesn't help I would try contacting Heroku's support. I have never encountered this issue before.

Comment: @DVN-Anakin, forgot password send me a mail with a link, but click on link get the same UI, ask verification code.